# how to View Details In separate page Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to display the details of a Service Provider in different page when the user click on view more details link button from the database , I tried many ways and didn't get the wanted result ,, could you Please help me

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="music.aspx.cs" Inherits="Flowers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
Runat="Server">


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:PartyZoneConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM 
[ServiceP] WHERE ([ServiceName] = @ServiceName)">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="music" Name="ServiceName" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
OnItemCommand="SP_ItemCommand" RepeatColumns="4" 
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("ServiceProviderName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="86px" 
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ServiceProviderImage") %>' Width="142px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="detailsButton" runat="server"
Text=<%#"more detailes about " + Eval("ServiceProviderName")%>

                 ></asp:LinkButton>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>

   </asp:Content>
```

Comment: What are you doing with `asp:LinkButton ID="detailsButton"` in your code behind?

Comment: I redirect to the details page ,but i don't know how to redirect the service provider id and how to use it again in the details page to retrieve the information for this service provider , I hope you understand me

Comment: Ah ok. So that means the code you posted above is not part of the problem. The problem is that you're loading a url (say serviceProvider.aspx?id=2) and you don't know how to get the reference to that id to use in your data query, yes? You should repost your question with those details, including how you're trying to get and use the id

Comment: Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).